Initialized variable defaults to 0
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TeamLead(1);
    }

    public static class TeamLead extends Programmer {

        private int numTeamLead=2;

        public TeamLead(int numTeamLead) {
            super(numTeamLead);
            this.numTeamLead = numTeamLead;
            employ();
        }

        protected void employ() {
            System.out.println(numTeamLead + " teamlead");
        }

    }

    public static class Programmer {

        private final int numProgrammer;

        public Programmer(int numProgrammer) {
            this.numProgrammer = numProgrammer;
            employ();
        }

        protected void employ() {
            System.out.println(numProgrammer + " programmer");
        }
    }
}


Why is the first output 0 teamlead instead of 2 teamlead?
I declared numTeamLead=2 before executing employ() and yet the first time employ() is executed, numTeamLead defaults to 0 for some reason. I know that the super(numTeamLead) cannot use the Programmer.employ() because it is protected, so it uses TeamLead.employ() instead. But why then does it default numTeamLead to 0 before using employ() again, even though I already initialized numTeamLead prior to executing any method?

Instance fields of a sublass are initialized after the superclass constructor completes. Since the call to the overridden employ() method happens already in the superclass constructor, the numTeamLead=2 initialization did not execute yet. Therefore, the numTeamLead field remains set to its default value - 0.
This is described specifically in JLS Chapter 12. Execution § 12.5. Creation of New Class Instances:

...

This constructor does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation of another constructor in the same class (using this). If this constructor is for a class other than Object, then this constructor will begin with an explicit or implicit invocation of a superclass constructor (using super). Evaluate the arguments and process that superclass constructor invocation recursively using these same five steps. If that constructor invocation completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason. Otherwise, continue with step 4.

Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers for this class, assigning the values of instance variable initializers to the corresponding instance variables, in the left-to-right order in which they appear textually in the source code for the class. If execution of any of these initializers results in an exception, then no further initializers are processed and this procedure completes abruptly with that same exception. Otherwise, continue with step 5.


...

The fragments in bold are applicable to your case - the superclass instance gets initialized first in its entirety and only after that initialization completes, the subclass initializers are executed.
Why not let the subclass initializers run first? In OOP approach, the subclass knows about the superclass, but the superclass does not (necessarily) know about its subclasses. So a subclass should be free to use superclass state in its constructor, ie. expect that the superclass state is entirely initialized when the subclass constructor runs. So it's consistent to expect that all superclass initialization happens before any subclass initialization.
OP's question from a comment:

Shouldn't this execution of employ fail to resolve numTeamLead?

The field exists in the subclass and the JLS defines the order of initialization, so instead of getting an error we get a deterministic state.

conclusion: do not call an overridden/overridable method from the constructor of the same class (the instance is not yet fully constructed, calling its methods can have unexpected results)

I kinda deduced that, but how come the field is declared but not initialized? Shouldn't it be declared and initialized together (and so shouldn't this execution of employ fail to resolve numTeamLead)?

@30pct declaration is more a compile time thing, initialization is runtime -- For details see 15.9.4. Run-Time Evaluation of Class Instance Creation Expressions: "space is allocated for the new class instance. ...  As each new field instance is created, it is initialized to its default value ... the selected constructor of the specified class is invoked. ... specified in detail in §12.5"

@30pct I expanded with some details from JLS and answered your question in an edit to the answer

Cuz spec.
Bit of a boring answer, let me elaborate:
Field declarations break apart into 2 utterly unrelated types:
Constant expressions - which are stored directly in the class file and essentially always have that value, consistently, everywhere, and are even inlined. Your field is not one of those because to be a CTC, your field must be assigned as it is declared (check), must be assigned a so-called compile-time constant expression (check; '2' is, naturally, compile-time constant), and must be final (fail) and must be static (fail also).
That means it's a plain jane field, which means the initializing expression is executed as part of the object instantiation process.
You can manually observe this and manually write them:
class Test {
  {
     // wait just.. braces... here?
     System.out.println("Hi there!");
  }
}

That's an instance initializer. What you wrote is syntax sugar for:
class TeamLead extends Programmer {
  private int numTeamLead;

  { numTeamLead = 2; } // instance initializer

        public TeamLead(int numTeamLead) {
            super(numTeamLead);
            this.numTeamLead = numTeamLead;
            employ();
        }
    }

You might now be asking: Huh - that seems.. kinda dumb. Why not just.. create that field into existence as having the value '2' right off the bat, just like public static final int FOO = 2; would have? Hey, if the class file format can support it, why not, right?
But.. the spec says no. Note that this is fine:
class Example {
  long foo = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

and naturally given that cTM's value depends on when you execute it, the spec must be clear on when that is executed. We can't just handwave that away as 'oh hey the value is always just that, it isn't ever not that, and there is not really such a thing as "execute it", it always has that value' in light of that. So, the spec needs to say something about when it is executed.
To make crystal clear how it all works:
class A {
  static String print(String in) {
   System.out.println(in);
   return in;
  }

  static { System.out.println("Static init A"); }
  { System.out.println("Instance init A"); }

  private String field = print("Instance init A2");

  A() { System.out.println("Constructor A"); }
  { System.out.println("Instance init A3"); }
}

class B extends A {
  static { System.out.println("Static init B"); }
  { System.out.println("Instance init B"); }

  private String field2 = print("Instance init B2");

  B() { System.out.println("Constructor B"); }
  { System.out.println("Instance init B3"); }
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new B();
  }
}

and this prints:
Static init A
Static init B
Instance init A
Instance init A2
Instance init A3
Constructor A
Instance init B
Instance init B2
Instance init B3
Constructor B

In other words, the entire 'init' process of A finished completely, including the constructor, before any of B's initializers run.
Why? Seriously, 'because' - the spec decrees this is how it is. The spec needs to spell out something. This is what was chosen.
In particular:

static initializers run before anything else
Parent classes fully init before children do
initializers run before constructors regardless of where the constructor appears in the source file
initializers run lex-order (higher up in the source file runs first).
Any expressions assigned directly to a field as they are declared are an initializer. They run after any initializers that appear above them and befor any that appear below them, they run before the constructor in that class regardless of whether it is above or below it. They run after both any initializers and any constructors of the parent.


So numTeamLead is declared, but it is not initialized until after the constructor of the parent runs?

Correct, @30pct
